Reprojecting GeoTools TileLayer
I connect to a tileService (OpenStreetMap) which I understand is in Mercator projection.
This shown correct in EPSG:3395 and EPSG:4636.
then I zoom in to a view inside the extent of UTM33N and change the viewing CRS to EPSG:32633 i get the following result:

Then I open a WSM connection and do the same, which gives me this correct result:

Is there a way to get the projection of the tiles correct?

The OSM tile client is not really designed to do anything other than display unaltered OSM tiles in EPSG:3857 as a basemap. I'm not surprised it doesn't reproject, enhancements to the module are always welcome.
